# UIBinder and using event propogation

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Prior to UIBinder in gwt, I wrapped elements in a HTMPanel which basically handled all the events for its child elements. So instead of attaching an eventlistener to multiple widgets, I just attached it to the parent container and used event bubbling.  Can I do this in UIBinder? I know in the backing class for the yourclass.ui.xml, you can use UiHandler to handle event delegation but is this optimal? Am I still adding multiple listeners or is GWT doing something behind the scenes and attaching only 1 event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an HTMLPanel and attach handlers to it using UiBinder:

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="myHtmlPanel">
  <h1>A Header</h1>
  <p>A Paragraph</p>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

And then, in your view:

```
@UiField HTMLPanel myHtmlPanel;

...

@UiHandler("myHtmlPanel")
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  // Handle the event.
}
```